# Retrieve password Tomcat authentication

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, servlets

Looking for a way to capture user password in case of Tomcat form-based authentication so that i can send the username/password combination to another application.
This is what i have so far:-

```
  Principal principal = req.getUserPrincipal();
      PropertyDescriptor[] pds;
      pds = PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(principal.getClass());
      for(int i = 0; i < pds.length; i++){
          try {
              String name = pds[i].getName();
              Object value = PropertyUtils.getProperty(principal,name);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
```

How can i grab the password out of object?
Would highly appreciate if anyone can provide recommendation around the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the name property to see it equals `password` and the corresponding value will be your password.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to intercept the password earlier in the login sequence but I would hope you *can't* do it this way, otherwise security would be badly broken.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is a really bad idea, it breaks all kinds of tenets about how to handle secure credentials. The OAuth protocol was developed to address this problem - I suggest you look into it to see if you can it instead.